# Convert full location degree to java degree

Tags: java, type-conversion, trigonometry

I'm able to get some location degrees in a format like these:

N 7°7'23,2716"

E 6°19'16,72428"

But I'm not sure how I should convert it to the double value that represents a degree in java, apart from the fact that I should take the degree, the minutes and the seconds  from my string and do something with them.

Comment: convert everything into seconds

Comment: @Berto99, you mean everything from the minutes part? As seen here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-toradians-method-example/#:~:text=lang.,to%20radian%20is%20generally%20inexact., the degree part is always before the decimal point in the double value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Berto99 said, convert everything into seconds. But you also need to add the degrees. So you have:

> Decimal Degrees = degrees + (minutes/60) + (seconds/3600)

So in your examples, N 7°7'23,2716", E 6°19'16,72428"

> N 7°7'23,2716" = 7 degrees + (7/60) + (23.2716/3600) = +7.123131

> E 6°19'16,72428" = 6 degrees + (19/60) + (16.72428/3600) = +6.3213123

**Beware of the minus sign** If the N changes to an S, or the E changes to a W, then stick a minus sign in front of the decimal number.